# mySQL sql error

Tags: sql, mysql

I am supposed to get all the rows where an id matches another id...

This is code, I have to link 2 tables...

```
SELECT *
  FROM acw_papers_web
  WHERE id_paper_web = ( SELECT id_paper_web
                           FROM acw_papers_web_autores
                           WHERE nombre_autor_pw LIKE'%Chicaiza%' )
```

I get the error: `Subquery returns more than 1 row`

I noticed why...

But insted of fixing it with a php code (i'm working with that) that gets each id and sends the query for each one of those, I'd like to do it with sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use `EXISTS()` instead of `IN()`, which might be a little bit faster.

```
SELECT a.id_paper_web 
  FROM acw_papers_web as a 
  WHERE  
  EXISTS
  (
    SELECT b.id_paper_web 
    FROM acw_papers_web_autores as b
    WHERE b.nombre_autor_pw like '%Chicaiza%' AND b.id_paper_web = a.id_paper_web
  )
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f0e3/1)**

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to assign multiple values to a `=` condition:

use `in` instead:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    acw_papers_web 
WHERE 
    id_paper_web in (
        SELECT 
            id_paper_web 
        FROM 
            acw_papers_web_autores 
        WHERE 
            nombre_autor_pw like '%Chicaiza%'
            )
```

Comment: Or, equivalently, `= ANY` or `= SOME`.

Comment: @eggyal Holy batman biscuits! You have taught me a new syntax today! +1

Answer (score 1):

You can change the = to IN.

```
SELECT * FROM acw_papers_web WHERE id_paper_web IN (SELECT id_paper_web FROM acw_papers_web_autores WHERE nombre_autor_pw like '%Chicaiza%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the =sign with an operator IN:

```
SELECT * FROM acw_papers_web
WHERE id_paper_web IN (
    SELECT id_paper_web FROM acw_papers_web_autores
    WHERE nombre_autor_pw like '%Chicaiza%'
)
```